# Subtitution of a DIV by a MUL, why does this work?

Tags: assembly, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned f( unsigned u )
{
    return u / 10;
}
```

Surprisingly the compiler generates the following code from this:

```
mov     eax, 0xcccccccd
mul     ecx
shr     edx, 3
mov     eax, edx
ret
```

So why does this work, i.e. why aren't there rounding errors ?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant.

Comment: There are rounding errors, but since it is truncated to an integer anyway, they don’t affect the final result.

Comment: https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html